# How to get PRIMARY KEY COLUMNS of a table (in case of COMPOSITE primary key)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a table that has composite primary key.

I am doing an update on that table and in the where clause I need the name of primary columns.
Till now I have been using:

```
 string sql = "SELECT PrimaryColumnName = col.column_name
               FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
                 INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col
                   ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name 
                     AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema
               WHERE tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key'
                 AND col.Table_name = '" + TABLE NAME HERE + "'";
```

To get the primary key column. However it fails where the primary key is composite.
How do I do the update here?
Help.

Comment: Please always use [parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 3):

The following query will get all primary key columns:

```
SELECT  c.Name
FROM    [sys].[index_columns] ic
        INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] c
            ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
            AND ic.[column_id] = c.[column_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] i
            ON i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
            AND i.[index_id] = ic.[index_id]
WHERE   i.is_primary_key = 1
AND     ic.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56fd7/2)**

*As has been noted in a comment you should be using parameterised queries.*

Comment: Thanks, was banging my head against the wall looking for this info

Answer (score 1):

Use the command objects for a pass values as parameters to SQL statements, providing type checking and validation

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
      string schemaName = "yourSchemaName";
      string tableName = "yourTableName";
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"
        SELECT column_name
        FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName
          AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
        ORDER BY table_schema, table_name", conn);
      command.Parameters.Add("@schemaName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = schemaName;
      command.Parameters.Add("@tableName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = tableName;
      conn.Open();                
      SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      try
      {                    
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
          }
      }

      finally
      {
          reader.Close();
      }

 }
```

Comment: **[USE PARAMETERIZED QUERIES!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)** Advocating the use of `String.Format` to build queries is not good advice! Also this line `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));` could be shortened to `Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);`

Comment: @GarethD that's realy good point! String.Format replaced by the SqlParameter object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SELECT the table name 
And press Alt+F1
You will get all the details required .

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be just fine. I’ve tested it and it returned all columns primary key is consisted of.

Try running this in SSMS and you’ll get two

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    SomeTextColumn nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    SomeColumn nvarchar(20),
    SomeOtherColumn uniqueidentifier,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID, SomeTextColumn)
)


 SELECT PrimaryColumnName = col.column_name 
 FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
 INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name 
 AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema 
 WHERE tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key' AND col.Table_name = 'T1'
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9e74/1/0) example for this.

If you need to filter this by column you can always add `“and col.COLUMN_NAME = 'ID'”`